# Python: Copy a Row Value and Add to Another Row where a cell is empty

Tags: python, pandas, copy, pandas-loc

Trying to figure out how to do this in pandas but currently can't figure it out.

I would like to copy a value from Col A where a cell in Col B is blank and add it to the below rows, only until it reaches the next blank cell in Col B where it will then start again.

My Python isn't the strongest so any pointers would be appreciated as i currently haven't got a clue where to start with this one! I have included the below as an example as to how it currently is and as to how I'd like it. I'm currently just manipulating and cleaning the data in Pandas.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Supply Voltage | BLANK |
| Rated Value | 10 |
| Limit | 20 |
| Size | BLANK |
| Height | 10 |
| Width | 20 |

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Supply Voltage | BLANK |
| Supply Voltage - Rated Value | 10 |
| Supply Voltage - Limit | 20 |
| Size | BLANK |
| Size - Height | 10 |
| Size - Width | 20 |

[Alessandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17203221/alessandro) answers the original question perfectly however in my case the data is something like this in my format. Where there are boolean Yes/No and unique values mixed in. Would a groupby and fill still work in this case?

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Supply Voltage | BLANK |
| Rated Value | 10 |
| Limit | 20 |
| Work | Yes |
| Size | BLANK |
| Height | 11 |
| Depth | 14 |
| Width | 55 |
| Description | BLANK |
| Time | 1432 |
| Date | 10/12/2022 |
| Quote | Hello World |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you can find a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Recreate example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['Supply Voltage', 'Rated Value', 'Limit', 'Size', 'Height', 'Width'],
    'B': [np.nan, 10, 20, np.nan, 10, 20]
})


# Add helper column (UPDATE)
l = []
c = 0
for i in df['B']:
    if pd.isnull(i):
        c = c+1
    l.append(c)
df['C'] = l

# Extract names associated with blank cells
blank_names = df.loc[df['B'].isna(), ['A', 'C']]
blank_names.columns = ['BLANK_NAME', 'C']

# Add names associated with blank cells to original DataFrame
df = df.merge(blank_names, on='C', how='left')
df['A'] = np.where(df['B'].notna(), df['BLANK_NAME'] + ' - ' + df['A'], df['A'])

# Display final output
df = df.drop(columns=['C', 'BLANK_NAME'])
df
```

Comment: Awwww man this works perfectly in this example, although I wasn't clear in my original data, so it is very close. The issue lies in the fact that data in Col B is all a mix of unique and the same, and I cannot figure out how to do it. I can see how fillna and groupby come to a solution in this example but I can't see how it would work for me.

Comment: Edited comment above has solved this for me. Thanks a lot!! Been a learning experience working your code out and seeing how it's doing it. Thank you again.

Comment: Hello, my code was working but just for your particular example. I am doing a new edit with a more general solution. Glad to help!